# Using development build of Firebase? Twitter authentication issue

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, authentication, vuex

I am currently trying to create a login using Twitter authentication with Vue.js, Vuex and Firebase. I've been following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@okpalachuks/twitter-authentication-with-vue-vuex-and-firebase-1f65f68dc0b0) and essentially used the exact code. When I run the application on my local host (npm run serve), the console has the following message:

> It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
>   When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
>   the individual SDK components you intend to use.

Is the issue with my Firebase? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

[This is the error in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyNib.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning just indicates that you are importing *all Firebase SDKs* instead of scoping it to the products you need. Currently your tutorial has:

```
import firebase from "firebase";
```

The [getting started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) has a snippet for how this should work instead:

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

// If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics
import "firebase/analytics";

// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! I added this to my main.js and still have an issue. I have attached a picture above if you could take a quick look. Thanks! :)

Comment: Make sure you're not importing directly from `"firebase"` anywhere in your code -- that's going to be the thing that triggers the warning. Other than that, make sure that your code is actually being rebuilt.

Comment: ;-bleigh I removed it from store.js and removed the error. Thank you! I still have 'waiting for update signal from WDS' and a vue warning (in picture above) Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not a Vue expert so this is the end of the road for my helpful tips :)